# Does outer join work if the field hasn't been created?

Tags: sql

I have a field that only gets created when the field is populated (i.e. the field does not contain a value, is not blank, and is not null). I am using an outer join on this field but only getting back the records that an inner join would give me. Am I correct in assuming that an outer join only returns records for values, blanks, and nulls in the given field?

Comment: This needs a lot more detail. What database are you asking about?

Comment: Show the SQL used.  My guess is you have a where clause on a right side of a left join which is eliminating the records from the 1st table.  "Am I correct in assuming that an outer join only returns records for values, blanks, and nulls in the given field?" No.  `Select * from A FULL OUTER JOIN B on A.ID = B.A_ID` would return all records from A and B and link those that had the same A.ID and B.A_ID in both.  See [Visual explanation of joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)  Big fan of picture for 1000 words.

Comment: Also, explain the concept of how a field doesn't exist unless it has data.

Comment: *"does not contain a value, is not blank, and is not null"*, well, that's impossible. And you don 't *"create a field"*
 :-)

Comment: If you're asking whether you can join on a field that doesn't yet exist, then no. Any field you wish to include in any clause of SQL query needs to exist before the query is executed.

Comment: Maybe you're generating a row number or something and want to join on it.  By using a CTE or encasing the select with row_number in a subqery the engine is forced to generate that dataset making the column available.  Maybe that's what you're after.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock, thank you that helps answers my question, if a field exists for some records and not others I assume the same would apply

Answer (score 0):

If a column does not exist in a table *and* the column is referenced in a query, then the query will generate a syntax error.

This has nothing to do with how the column is being used or the type of `join`.

Comment: This field exists/is defined for some records but not all

Comment: @Cameron If record exists, but no value, it is usually NULL.

Comment: If all the records come from the same table, the field will either exist or not exist for all of them.   That's how databases work.

Comment: @DanBracuk, there are two tables, some of the records in the first table have a corresponding record in the second table and some do not, when I outer left join the first table to the second I only get records that were on both tables returned

Comment: @Cameron . . . The column exists in the result set.  The value is `NULL` for the unmatched records.